# transform dataframe column to vector(character) in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I am newbee to R.

The code I'm working with is a bit more detailed, but I've tried to code a reproducible example here which captures all the key bits: a data frame ,for example:

```
   df=  x y    z
    1  1  2   cat
    2  1  3   dog
    3  1  4   pig
```

I want to transform df[3] to

pet<-c("cats","dogs","pigs")

then

```
 tt<-list()
for (animal in pet) { tt[1]<-paste("animal","is so cute!",sep="")
```

I want to get :

```
tt[1]
"cats is so cute!"
tt[2]
"dogs is so cute!"
……
```

Thanks for your any comments.

Comment: Why not just `pet <- paste0(df[,3],'s')` and `paste(pet, 'is so cute!')` as `paste` is vectorized.
`

Comment: @akrun but df[,3] is not a vector!  it doesnot work for loops. and the real dimension of df is 500+,how to realize it ?

Comment: `is.vector(df[,3])#[1] TRUE`  Why you need loops here?  As I mentioned, paste is vectorized.

Comment: If you need to loop `tt <- vector('list', length(pet));
 for(i in seq_along(pet)){ tt[[i]] <- paste(pet[i], 'is so cute!')}; unlist(tt)
#[1] "cats is so cute!" "dogs is so cute!" "pigs is so cute!"
 `

Comment: Regaring the 500+ dimension, is it `ncols`? Sorry, I didn't get the question.

Comment: sorry，@akrun, I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One nice feature of R is that you do not need to explicitly use loops, as many operations treat this implicitly. this works:

```
tt <- paste(df$z,'is...')
```

because df$z is a vector, and paste takes a vector as an input. You can see that the output of paste is a vector of strings:

```
str(tt)
chr [1:3] "cat is..." "dog is..." "pig is..."
```